# how to change the content of the lightdom using jquery.javascript

Tags: jquery, polymer

Say i have an custom element written like this

```
<custom>Test<custom>
```

How do I go about changing the light dom content after its been resolved into shadyDOM.

Using the standard `$("custom").text("test1");` does not works as it damage the tree structure of the shadyDOM

Answer (score 0):

You can manipulate the DOM as well as custom element properties and behavior after it's been resolved into the shadow or shady DOM by using Polymer's native `ready` callback as [described here](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/registering-elements.html#ready-method).

You don't need jquery. You can just use the `Polymer()` function inside your element's `<script>` tag as follows:

**Example code:**

```
<script>
  (function() {
    Polymer({
      is: 'example-element',
      properties: {...},
      ready: function() {
        // access a local DOM element by ID using this.$
        this.$.header.textContent = 'Hello!';
      }
    });
  })();
</script>
```